# Create subdomain with limited access for selected user only php apache

Tags: php, apache, cpanel

Well I need a solution for creating subdomains (directories) for only selected user access.

1. User "exampleuser" register on site -> example.com
2. User gets own subdomain -> exampleuser.example.com
3. Only "exampleuser" has access to subdomain -> exampleuser.example.com
4. "exampleuser" can use put_file_content / file etc function only in his directory
5. "exampleuser" can't access other users directories with put_file_content, include etc...

I need it because users can upload their own .php scripts to their dirs but can't do anything outside their subdomain (directories)

Comment: This is off-topic. The answer is far too broad to sensibly answer here. So, the suggestion would be to research the topic and then if you encounter any specific difficulties in implementing your chosen strategy, come back and ask for help with them.

Comment: You are unlikely to get an answer. SO is not about answering general questions like this, it's for giving practical answers to specific programming problems. This isn't a problem, it's a request to be taught a generalised principle of web development and is therefore off topic for this site.

Answer (score 0):

You can create FTP account for your every subdomains account and provide that details to client to upload php file in subdomains document root.

Answer (score 0):

the best way is to create directory ownership and assign it to the user. Like if you have three sub domains than you have to create 3 users and assign them ownership of respective public_html folder. For rest of the directories you can use ROOT USER as the owner.

I use following command to create the ownership -

chown username:group directory